# passing intent between for two string arrays

Tags: android, arrays, string, android-intent

I have two string Arrays, contactNames in the main Activity class, and address [] in the second activity class. when i click on the one of the names, it should show me the address details for that name. How should I create an intent for two string arrays in Android.

**class ContactList**

```
    Intent i = new Intent (MainActivity.this, Details.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle ();
    bundle.putStringArray("key", address);
    i.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

**class Details**

```
 Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        String array [] = b.getStringArray("key");
    tvEmail.setText(array.toString());                      
    }
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> How should I create an intent for two string arrays in Android.

You can add another array (or any other data type) but you need to use a different `key` name. Example...

```
String[] array1;
String[] array2;

// Populate arrays here

Intent i = new Intent (MainActivity.this, Details.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle ();
bundle.putStringArray("key1", array1);
bundle.putStringArray("key2", array2);
i.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(i);
```

Also note that you don't need to use a `Bundle` directly. You can use the `Intent` method `putExtra(String name, String[] value)`. For example...

```
String[] array1;
String[] array2;

// Populate arrays here

Intent i = new Intent (MainActivity.this, Details.class);
i.putExtra("key1", array1);
i.putExtra("key2", array2);
startActivity(i);
```